# How to dynamically add a text

Tags: javascript, text

I was just wondering if there was a way to dynamically add a text?
You can add an image like this:

```
var img1 = new Image(); // DOM 0
img1.src = 'image1.png';
img1.alt = 'alt';
document.body.appendChild(img1);
```

Would you do --V-- ??

```
var Txt = new Text();
```

Thanks!

*EDIT*: 
I how would I move this text??

Thanks!

Comment: `var txt = document.createTextNode("text")`

Comment: Also. Why did I get - points for this question??

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: Hmm so basically if the computer thinks I didn't necessarily need to ask the question then it gives me -points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what do you mean, to attach a text element you just need to create a text node with

```
document.createTextNode("whatever you want to write")
```

and then attach it to the body or wathever div you want.

**Edit**

Esailija already gave you the right answer.

Comment: OK well I would like to be able to add the text from within the script. Also, would I be able to move this??

Comment: So in case you didn't get it., I'm *VERY* new to javascript :)

Comment: No problem :D, in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode) you can find all you need, as you can see the appendChild appens inside a script, in this case it depends on a button and attaches it to the p1 element, you need to modify it on your needs.

Comment: Since you're new to JS (I am too by the way) to select different items you just need to change the 
    var para = document.getElementById("p1");